# Why do constraints prefer resizing of one stack over another, and how do you change this preference? (xCode)

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I am trying to use constraints in xCode for Auto Layout purposes, but I am running into an issue. Shown here is the current layout of the app:
[Current Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrqL1.png). I have two stacks, one on top and one on bottom. I have constrained the position of the top stack to be glued to the top, left, and right Safe Areas, and have constrained the bottom stack to be glued to the bottom, left, and right Safe Areas. I now want to constrain the top stack to be equal to some small spacing above the bottom stack, with only the **Top Stack** stretching if necessary, with the **Bottom Stack** staying totally stationary. Instead, I am getting the opposite, with the **Bottom Stack** rushing up to meet the **Top Stack**. How did xCode choose to make the Bottom Stack stretch, but not the top, and how do I fix this?

Here is a gif showing the problem I am having. Note that I had set the Bottom Stack to be Distributed at the bottom, so it doesn't initially appear to have stretched, but once I switch from bottom to fill you quickly see the issue: [Constraint Problem Gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZzaw.gif).

Thanks.

Comment: either give a fixed height to your bottom stack view or keep bottom stack view vertical hugging priority and compression resistance higher than you top stack view

Answer (score 1):

The aspect of autolayout that you're looking for is both contentHuggingPriority and contentCompressionResistancePriority. These determine which views are more likely to stretch or compress.

Increase the vertical contentHuggingPriority of the lower stack to greater than that of the top stack, then the autolayout system will make the top stack stretch.

Comment: I tried this, but unfortunately it didn't work. I changed the vertical contentHuggingPriority and the vertical contentCompressionResistancePriority to 100 for the bottom stack and 1 for the top stack, and unfortunately nothing has changed. Is there anything else you think could be causing the issue?

Comment: The default for many views is between 500 and 750, so something else may be getting in the way. Try *just* setting the vertical contentHuggingPriority for the lower stack to .required, aka 1000?

Comment: Got it! I just reordered my buttons, it was much simpler. Although the contentHuggingPriority does appear to do somethings sometimes. I appreciate the help!